# AppStore App Compatibility Difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I noticed that there is a different between my app compatibility and another apps in the AppStore.

In my app it's look like this:

[image]

And in the other apps it's look like this:

[image]

You can see that at my app it's give a full list. What can be the problem\difference between the two apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your app is only available for 64-bit devices, the other apps are for 32 and 64 bit devices. This may be caused by an extension for your app or a framework which is only available on 64 bit devices.

For more information see the Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html

Comment: So i need to add `armv7s` and `armv7` to the `Valid Architectures`? Now i only have there `arm64`

Comment: Yes, then your app should support 32 bit devices